# Revoke plus.login

Tags: php, youtube, google-plus, token

On my website there are authorization processes for Google+ and YouTube.
A user can add his Google+ or YouTube Account to his profile on my website.

**Scopes**:

1. Google+: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`
2. YouTube: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`

When a user add both to his profile, so there are two entries on [subtokens page](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=de).
One for Google+ Login and the other for YouTube.

**Scenario**:

A user want to remove the Youtube-Account from the profile on my website.
=> I delete the entry in the database and revoke the token with the GoogleAuth function (`revokeToken()`).
After I revoked the YouTube token there is only one entry left on [subtokens page](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=de) (Google+ Login).

But when the user wants only to remove the Google+ from the profile on my website and I use the same GoogleAuth Function (`revokeToken()`), then both entries will be revoked and there isn't an entry on subtokens page.

Why will the YouTube entry also revoked? I just want to revoke the Google+ Login.

Is there a solution for this problem?

**Edit (06.08.2013)**

When I check the tokens on `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=TOKEN`, I get following results:

**1. YouTube Token:**

> ```
> "issued_to": "......",
>
> "audience": "......",
>
> "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
>
> "expires_in": 3272,
>
> "access_type": "offline"
> ```

**2. Google+ Token**

> ```
> "issued_to": "......",
>
>  "audience": "......",
>
>  "user_id": "......",
>
>  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
>
>  "expires_in": 3093,
>
>  "access_type": "offline"
> ```

The tokens have different scopes, but why will be the YouTube-token revoked once I revoke the Google+ Token?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login has a [policy](https://developers.google.com/+/policies) that requires developers to implement disconnect.  To disconnect you need to revoke your access token, which revokes all Google scopes that your application has requested for that user.

I'm not sure why your application would be requesting only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly on one occasion and then https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login on a separate occasion.

A better approach might be to request a single access token with the full list of scopes you require based on what the user has enabled.

Comment: A user should have the option to decide whether he add only Google+ or YouTube (maybe he don't want to add YouTube or Google+, so he add which he want). Also he can add both to his profile, when he it one after another.

Comment: That's the reason why I request "plus.login" and "youtube.readonly" separately.
Is there no possibilty to revoke single token (Google+ or YouTube)? Both have different access tokes and refresh tokens. 
When I revoke the YouTube-token then the Google+ token persist. Why the other way around it doesn't work?

Comment: There's no possibility to revoke a single token when you request plus.login.  I think the intended implementation pattern is that if a user wants to connect YouTube you request a token with youtube.readonly.  If they want Google+ access you request a new token with both youtube.readonly and plus.login (or plus.me).  If they then want to disconnect Google+ access you would revoke the token and request a new token with youtube.readonly.